# Subclassing - Text edit smillar to iText

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm subclassing a Rect class to make own element called "Button". It haves text inside, i want a provide edit text tool smillar to iText(double click allow edit)
How to reach this?
Custom component code:

```
export class Button extends fabric.Rect {


  public text: string;
  public textColor: string;
  public font = '30px Arial';
  public action: ActionEnum;


  constructor(options: IButttonOptions) {
    super(options);
    if  (options.font) {
      this.font = options.font;
    }
    this.text = options.text;
    this.textColor = options.textColor;
    this.action = options.action;
  }

  _render (ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
    super._render(ctx);
    ctx.font = this.font;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.textColor;
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillText(this.text, 0, 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: create rect and itext object and group it.

Comment: @Durga edit iText didnt work in group